# i want to use gurmukhi (punjabi) in my xml data file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to use Gurmukhi (Punjabi language) in my xml file. but it isn't working.

This is the Gurmukhi (Punjabi) text which I want to use in my xml:

[image]

But when I copy the above text to my xml file, it turns into this:

[image]

Comment: What steps exactly are you taking?

Comment: I am using this xml in a windows phone 8.1 Silverlight databound application. and if I copy Punjabi language directly to xml file it appeared in English language as shown above. and if I change font to Punjabi then the whole document changes to Punjabi.

Answer (score 0):

Install the .ttf file for your Gurmukhi font and link it to your text.

Comment: I've installed the Gurmukhi font in my machine as well as in the asset folder of my project but nothing changed. and even if I change the font in notepad whole document turn's into Gurmukhi.